# Parametric function differentiation problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$x=a \cos g(t) \text{ and }  y=b\sin g(t)$$
$$ xy^2\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=b^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Could somebody help me with this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Please include what you have already tried; this is not a homework-solving machine!

Comment: I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: Why are you differentiating $y$ with respect to $x$ when it is being expressed as a function of $t$?

Comment: I understand that I should simply put derivatives into the second equation and show that the equation stands.

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ and $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$. Then,

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$$

$$\dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac d{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$ Now simply substitute $x, y$ into $\dfrac{dy}{dx},$ and $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx}$ and then all of these into your second equation.

Comment: I wish you a very deep slumber Amy in the Heaven. :-) Have a great weekend my dear friend.

Comment: @B.S. Thank you, dear Babak!

Answer (score 0):

It is noticed that eliminating $g(t)$ right at the start we need only to deal with two differentiations on a standard ellipse without parameter $\,t$:

$$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1\,\tag1$$

This may not be strictly in line with the aim of the exercise. Also it was on for 6 years.

So however to proceed denote primes with resp to $x,$

$$ \dfrac{x}{a^2}+ \dfrac{yy'}{b^2}=0;\, y^{'} =\dfrac{-xb^2}{ya^2}\tag2$$

$$ \dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{yy^{''}+yy^{'2}}{b^2} =0; \,y^{''}=\dfrac{-b^2/a^2 - y'^2}{y}\tag3$$

Plug in  2) and 3) into the given equation

$$ x y^2y^{''}- b^2y^{'}=0 \tag4$$

and simplify LHS:

$$ \dfrac{-x}{a^2 y}\cdot( \dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}-1)\ , \tag5$$

that vanishes.